# Postfix acts as sender for unathenticated connections on port 25 for $relay_domains

Tags: postfix, email-server, smtp

My postfix can be set as SMTP server on any email client, on port 25, no auth, to successfully deliver e-mail to any domain listed in $relay_domains.
This is bad, and can be easily used to send spam bypassing any restriction set to the submission port (587).

I am surely missing something, hope you can help me.

Here you can grab my postconf -f output (IP's and real hostnames have been replaced):

https://app.box.com/s/asblh2150kmpzr0ag5pp

Comment: This is expected behavior. For example: Gmail server must connect to port 25 **without auth** to deliver email from @gmail.com to your relay_domains.

Comment: I try to explain myself better with an example. If I set up my Thunderbird to use my email server as SMTP with no auth and port 25, I can send email to a known address belonging to my email server. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: **Yes**. Basically Gmail (in my example) and Thunderbird (in your example) both act as a **mail client** to send email TO your relay_domains.

Comment: I have put our discussion in the answer section below. Please consider to accept it so this question doesn't floating in [Unanswered Tab](http://serverfault.com/unanswered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My postfix can be set as SMTP server on any email client, on port 25, no auth, to successfully deliver e-mail to any domain listed in $relay_domains. This is bad, and can be easily used to send spam bypassing any restriction set to the submission port (587).

This is expected behavior. For example: Gmail server must connect to port 25 without auth to deliver email from @gmail.com to your `relay_domains`.

> I try to explain myself better with an example. If I set up my Thunderbird to use my email server as SMTP with no auth and port 25, I can send email to a known address belonging to my email server. Is this expected behavior?

Yes. Basically Gmail (in my example) and Thunderbird (in your example) both act as a mail client to send email TO your `relay_domains`.

---

The only concern is if you accept email from outside your `mynetwork` (without auth) and then deliver it to domain outside `relay_domains`. In that case, you have *successfully* created one free open relay.